# Send spoof locations with DDMS emulator control to a tablet android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, ddms

I want to test a GPS application I am developing in my android tablet, so I need to send to it spoof locations from a KML file loading it using DDMS. I want to use a physical device, not the emulator.

The problem is that the Emulator Control section in DDMS is disabled (grayed out) when I select my external device (the app process running) in the devices view. Insted if I select the emulator then the emulator control appears enabled but not with the physical device.

My applicaton has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

And my physical tablet is configured with:

- USB debugging.
- Allow mock locations

I'm using SDK r20 and my tablet has android 4.0.3.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: I have worked extensively with GPS applications and I never managed to achieve sending mock locations from the DDMS to a physical device.
Instead I added the KML (or other file format) to the app resources and wrote a parser to read the data from the file and inject it into my application in place of the Location updates for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking in your idea. Do you know any example that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

I've pieced together a solution to this problem.

- Go to **Settings->Applications->Development** and select "**Allow mock locations**".
- Add **ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION** permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION">
  ```
- Implement a class which uses the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).addTestProvider() function. This will indicate to the application that it should use data from a file to construct new Location objects.
- New Locations can then be created using the LocationManager.setTestProviderLocation() function.

  ```
  // start using mock locations
  try {
     mockLocationCreator = new MockLocationCreator(this.getApplicationContext());
     try {
         mockLocationCreator.openLocationList();

         mockLocationThread = new Thread(mockLocationCreator);
         mockLocationThread.start();

         Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Mock locations are in use", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error: Unable to open / read data file", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();
         mockLocationCreator = null;
     }
  } catch(SecurityException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Error: Insufficient Privileges", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
     Log.e(TAG, "unable to use mock locations, insufficient privileges", e);
  }
  ```

**Note:** It is not possible to send mock locations to a real device from DDMS->Emulator Control->Location Controls regardless of device or manifest permissions as is incorrectly suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794950/fake-location-using-gps-in-android#3798060).

---

Sources:

[Android mock location on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device) - information about manifest permissions and alternative solution using the telnet command line, links and code snippets.

[Using Mock Locations in Android](http://techxplorer.com/2011/07/01/using-mock-locations-in-android/) - more verbose, contains some dead links.

[LocationManager Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) - Official Android documentation

Answer (score 0):

For simple `spoofing` you can use [this free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation) but as you said in your question you want `spoof` locations from a `KML` file for that you have to buy [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.locationspooferpro)

Comment: Thanks. I tested that pro version and seems not to read very properly a little KML file that I created with the last version of Google Earth. I'm not sure if there are different versions of the KML files, so that app might have a compatibility problem.

Comment: you are welcome i never tested the pro version just read the description once and i saw your question and thought it might help you so i shared it with you.

Comment: I also tested this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forgottenprojects.mocklocations) that reads KML routes but now there is a issue with the KML file I'm using. The developer said me that is finishing a new corrected version.

Comment: okay but for now you can test your application by entering lat lon in the spoofer.I went through some tutorial and found If you have trouble with a particular KML file, make sure it has this: <kml
xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x">.

Comment: The [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forgottenprojects.mocklocations) I said, has been updated fixing the last issues with KML files. I tested the last version with a little KML file created with the last version of Google Earth and the results were succesful. I could simulate an entire route.