# Simulate localization in a Android device with debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, mocking, android-debug

I connect my tablet android galaxy 2 to my pc for debug my application with eclipse, it runs good but I am trying to simulate the location in a google map that I included into my app.

I try with [gps android simulator](http://code.google.com/p/android-gps-emulator/) and seems that it connect to the port (8600 in my case) it sends the location but nothing happens. And for example with  the port 5554 says that it can't connect.

After that, I tried with telnet: `telnet localhost 8600` but it did nothing, it did like a "clear" in console.

I have search on internet but I didnt found an answer.

I checked:

1. manifest: `<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />`
2. Android device settings to enable simulate location.

I am very frustated with it because I need it. Thanks for your replys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an app called [Fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en) on Play Store which might help. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device).

Comment: Yes I know, but I need change the location many times in the same session.

Comment: Be sure to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591333/send-spoof-locations-with-ddms-emulator-control-to-a-tablet-android-device). Also [this program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpsfeed/) looks interesting, but I have no idea if it works with an Android device.